# Closing Wordpress Twenty Fourteen mobile menu on click

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the wordpress twenty fourteen theme. When the site resizes down onto a mobile it automatically brings the menu toggle up, so you click it and the menu slides down. When I click a menu item, the page then slides down to reveal the content, the only problem is the menu doesn't close like it would if you were going to a new page.

Any ideas on how I can close the menu when an item is clicked?

EDIT:

I've ahd a look in the js code and noticed

```
button.on( 'click.twentyfourteen', function() {
        nav.toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
        if ( nav.hasClass( 'toggled-on' ) ) {
            $( this ).attr( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
            menu.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
        } else {
            $( this ).attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
            menu.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
        }
    } );
```

which seems to deal with the opening and closing of the menu, is there a way to apply that to the menu links so they close it when they are clicked?

EDIT 2

I've also found the following in the doucment ready code

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
        $('.main_nav').slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have any script error? if not, it's the behaviour of the theme. Usually, the *hamburguer* menu have a click event, so it adds or removes a class from the menu elem to display the `<ul>` menu or not. So, you can add a class for the `<li>` elems with anchor, and attach a new event "click" to the *hamburguer* to `add / remove` class or use `hide / show` functions.

Comment: i can't see any script errors for that, i just assumed it was because i'm using a parralax/scrolling page so it deosnt close as it scrolls down.

Comment: @Andy try another template page or put the link to see it.